# problem loading static files with django nginx gunicorn on AWS lightsail

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, amazon-lightsail

I installed my django app on lightsail, on a ubuntu server from scratch. The webpage is working ok but the static files are not loading. I read about adding some info on the web_app.conf (cht_web.conf) and it looks like this:

```
    `server {

    listen 80;
    
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    
    location / {
    
    include proxy_params;
    `
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    
    }
    
    location /static/ {
    
    autoindex on;
    root /home/ubuntu/cht_web/cht_web/static/;
    }
```

I´m not sure if i have to install Supervisor, so I´ve not installed it yet,

im running gunicorn with:

`gunicorn cht_web.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 4`
and the log is:

```
\[2023-11-20 12:47:13 +0000\] \[38774\] \[INFO\] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
\[2023-11-20 12:47:13 +0000\] \[38774\] \[INFO\] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (38774)
\[2023-11-20 12:47:13 +0000\] \[38774\] \[INFO\] Using worker: sync
\[2023-11-20 12:47:13 +0000\] \[38775\] \[INFO\] Booting worker with pid: 38775
\[2023-11-20 12:47:13 +0000\] \[38776\] \[INFO\] Booting worker with pid: 38776
\[2023-11-20 12:47:13 +0000\] \[38777\] \[INFO\] Booting worker with pid: 38777
\[2023-11-20 12:47:13 +0000\] \[38778\] \[INFO\] Booting worker with pid: 38778
```

my settings.py static config is:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles' #representa la raiz del directorio
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
```

my base dir is:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

(maybe the extra.parent is an issue, but it loads media!)

Its in debug = True mode

the media config is:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR /'media' MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

if i do pwd on the folder where static is :
`/home/ubuntu/cht_web/` 
The strange thing is that my media files do work with no configurations besides
please help :)

I tried changing the config file to root, tried changing the STATIC_ROOT  to     `/home/ubuntu/cht_web/`

Answer (score 1):

If `DEBUG` is set to `True` then you need to add the following snippet to `urls.py` at project level:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Reference: [Django Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)